# How to set a bundle installation location to its parent bundle directory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins, bundle

I have a main project `App` that contains subproject intended to be installed in `AppBundleDirectory/Contents/PlugIns`.

The default installation directory for `plugin.xcodeproj` is `/Library/Bundles`, I'd like to change it to `AppBundleDirectory/Contents/PlugIns`. I don't think `plugin` is aware of its parent build directory, so I couldn't find any environment variable to put into the `Installation Directory` setting.

To sum it up:

**Project structure**

```
App.xcodeproj
  Plugins/
    plugin1.xcodeproj
    plugin2.xcodeproj
```

**Wanted generated structure**

```
App.app
  Contents/
    Plugins/
      plugin1.bundle
      plugin2.bundle
```

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app target depends on your plugin targets, then it's fairly straightforward:

- Add a Copy Files phase to your app
- Make the Destination "PlugIns" (this is in the drop-down list)
- Use the "+" button to choose the plugins.

If the plugins depend on the app, then it's only slightly more complicated. You have to hard-code the name of the app:

- Make sure that everyone has the same DSTROOT (using a single Scheme is the easiest way to get this)
- Make the plugins INSTALL_PATH be "/App.app/Contents/PlugIns" (note the leading /)

Note that it's "PlugIns" not "Plugins". 99.99% of the time it doesn't matter. But every so often you run into that one guy who chooses a case-sensitive file system at install and your plugins don't load. I chased that bug for four months once. Picking it from the Copy Files list is a nice way to be sure to be right.